# Non-recursive enumeration of triply restricted positive integer compositions

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics

After creating an iterative (non-recursive) function, that enumerates **doubly** restricted [compositions of positive integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) in a lexicographic order, for a microcontroller with a very small amount of RAM (but large EPROM), I had to expand the number of restrictions to 3, namely to:

1. The restriction on the length of the composition
2. The restriction on the the minimum value of elements
3. The restriction on the the maximum value of elements

The original function, that generates the doubly restricted compositions is listed below:

```
void GenCompositions(unsigned int myInt, unsigned int CompositionLen, unsigned int MinVal)
{
    if ((MinVal = MinPartitionVal(myInt, CompositionLen, MinVal, (unsigned int) (-1))) == (unsigned int)(-1)) // Increase the MinVal to the minimum that is feasible.
        return;

    std::vector<unsigned int> v(CompositionLen);
    int pos = 0;
    const int last = CompositionLen - 1;


    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= last; ++i) // Generate the initial composition
        v[i] = MinVal;

    unsigned int MaxVal = myInt - MinVal * last;
    v[0] = MaxVal;

    do
    {
        DispVector(v);

        if (pos == last)
        {
            if (v[last] == MaxVal)
                break;

            for (--pos; v[pos] == MinVal; --pos);  //Search for the position of the Least Significant non-MinVal (not including the Least Significant position / the last position).
            //std::cout << std::setw(pos * 3 + 1) << "" << "v" << std::endl;    //DEBUG

            --v[pos++];
            if (pos != last)
            {
                v[pos] = v[last] + 1;
                v[last] = MinVal;
            }
            else
                v[pos] += 1;

        }
        else
        {
            --v[pos];
            v[++pos] = MinVal + 1;
        }

    } while (true);
}
```

The sample output of this funtion is:

```
GenCompositions(10,4,1);:
7, 1, 1, 1
6, 2, 1, 1
6, 1, 2, 1
6, 1, 1, 2
5, 3, 1, 1
5, 2, 2, 1
5, 2, 1, 2
5, 1, 3, 1
5, 1, 2, 2
5, 1, 1, 3
4, 4, 1, 1
4, 3, 2, 1
4, 3, 1, 2
4, 2, 3, 1
4, 2, 2, 2
4, 2, 1, 3
4, 1, 4, 1
4, 1, 3, 2
4, 1, 2, 3
4, 1, 1, 4
3, 5, 1, 1
3, 4, 2, 1
3, 4, 1, 2
3, 3, 3, 1
3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 1, 3
3, 2, 4, 1
3, 2, 3, 2
3, 2, 2, 3
3, 2, 1, 4
3, 1, 5, 1
3, 1, 4, 2
3, 1, 3, 3
3, 1, 2, 4
3, 1, 1, 5
2, 6, 1, 1
2, 5, 2, 1
2, 5, 1, 2
2, 4, 3, 1
2, 4, 2, 2
2, 4, 1, 3
2, 3, 4, 1
2, 3, 3, 2
2, 3, 2, 3
2, 3, 1, 4
2, 2, 5, 1
2, 2, 4, 2
2, 2, 3, 3
2, 2, 2, 4
2, 2, 1, 5
2, 1, 6, 1
2, 1, 5, 2
2, 1, 4, 3
2, 1, 3, 4
2, 1, 2, 5
2, 1, 1, 6
1, 7, 1, 1
1, 6, 2, 1
1, 6, 1, 2
1, 5, 3, 1
1, 5, 2, 2
1, 5, 1, 3
1, 4, 4, 1
1, 4, 3, 2
1, 4, 2, 3
1, 4, 1, 4
1, 3, 5, 1
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 3, 3
1, 3, 2, 4
1, 3, 1, 5
1, 2, 6, 1
1, 2, 5, 2
1, 2, 4, 3
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 2, 5
1, 2, 1, 6
1, 1, 7, 1
1, 1, 6, 2
1, 1, 5, 3
1, 1, 4, 4
1, 1, 3, 5
1, 1, 2, 6
1, 1, 1, 7
```

After adding the 3rd restriction (on the maximum value of elements), the complexity of the function increased significantly. This expanded function is listed below:

```
void GenCompositions(unsigned int myInt, unsigned int CompositionLen, unsigned int MinVal, unsigned int MaxVal)
{
    if ((MaxVal = MaxPartitionVal(myInt, CompositionLen, MinVal, MaxVal)) == 0) //Decrease the MaxVal to the maximum that is feasible.
        return;

    if ((MinVal = MinPartitionVal(myInt, CompositionLen, MinVal, MaxVal)) == (unsigned int)(-1))    //Increase the MinVal to the minimum that is feasible.
        return;

    std::vector<unsigned int> v(CompositionLen);
    unsigned int last = CompositionLen - 1;
    unsigned int rem = myInt - MaxVal - MinVal*(last-1);
    unsigned int pos = 0;

    v[0] = MaxVal;  //Generate the most significant element in the initial composition

    while (rem > MinVal){   //Generate the rest of the initial composition (the highest in the lexicographic order). Spill the remainder left-to-right saturating at MaxVal

        v[++pos] = ( rem > MaxVal ) ? MaxVal : rem;  //Saturate at MaxVal
        rem -= v[pos] - MinVal; //Deduct the used up units (less the background MinValues)
    }

    for (unsigned int i = pos+1; i <= last; i++)    //Fill with MinVal where the spillage of the remainder did not reach.
        v[i] = MinVal;


    if (MinVal == MaxVal){  //Special case - all elements are the same. Only the initial composition is possible.
        DispVector(v);
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        DispVector(v);

        if (pos == last)        
        {       
            for (--pos; v[pos] == MinVal; pos--) {  //Search backwards for the position of the Least Significant non-MinVal (not including the Least Significant position / the last position).
                if (!pos)   
                    return;
            }

            //std::cout << std::setw(pos*3 +1) << "" << "v" << std::endl;  //Debug

            if (v[last] >= MaxVal)  // (v[last] > MaxVal) should never occur
            {

                if (pos == last-1)  //penultimate position. //Skip the iterations that generate excessively large compositions (with elements > MaxVal).
                {   
                    for (rem = MaxVal; ((v[pos] == MinVal) || (v[pos + 1] == MaxVal)); pos--) { //Search backwards for the position of the Least Significant non-extremum (starting from the penultimate position - where the previous "for loop" has finished).  THINK:  Is the (v[pos] == MinVal) condition really necessary here ?
                        rem += v[pos];  //Accumulate the sum of the traversed elements
                        if (!pos)
                            return;
                    }
                    //std::cout << std::setw(pos * 3 + 1) << "" << "v" << std::endl;    //Debug

                    --v[pos];
                    rem -= MinVal*(last - pos - 1) - 1;  //Subtract the MinValues, that are assumed to always be there as a background

                    while (rem > MinVal)    // Spill the remainder left-to-right saturating at MaxVal
                    {
                        v[++pos] = (rem > MaxVal) ? MaxVal : rem;   //Saturate at MaxVal
                        rem -= v[pos] - MinVal; //Deduct the used up units (less the background MinValues)
                    }

                    for (unsigned int i = pos + 1; i <= last; i++)  //Fill with MinVal where the spillage of the remainder did not reach.
                        v[i] = MinVal;

                    continue;   //The skipping of excessively large compositions is complete. Nothing else to adjust...
                }

                /* (pos != last-1) */
                --v[pos];
                v[++pos] = MaxVal;
                v[++pos] = MinVal + 1;  //Propagate the change one step further. THINK: Why a CONSTANT value like MinVal+1 works here at all?

                if (pos != last)
                    v[last] = MinVal;

            }
            else    // (v[last] < MaxVal)
            {           
                --v[pos++];
                if (pos != last)
                {
                    v[pos] = v[last] + 1;
                    v[last] = MinVal;
                }
                else
                    v[pos] += 1;
            }
        }
        else    // (pos != last)
        {
            --v[pos];
            v[++pos] = MinVal + 1;  // THINK: Why a CONSTANT value like MinVal+1 works here at all ?
        }

    } while (true);
}
```

The sample output of this expanded funtion is:

```
GenCompositions(10,4,1,4);:
4, 4, 1, 1
4, 3, 2, 1
4, 3, 1, 2
4, 2, 3, 1
4, 2, 2, 2
4, 2, 1, 3
4, 1, 4, 1
4, 1, 3, 2
4, 1, 2, 3
4, 1, 1, 4
3, 4, 2, 1
3, 4, 1, 2
3, 3, 3, 1
3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 1, 3
3, 2, 4, 1
3, 2, 3, 2
3, 2, 2, 3
3, 2, 1, 4
3, 1, 4, 2
3, 1, 3, 3
3, 1, 2, 4
2, 4, 3, 1
2, 4, 2, 2
2, 4, 1, 3
2, 3, 4, 1
2, 3, 3, 2
2, 3, 2, 3
2, 3, 1, 4
2, 2, 4, 2
2, 2, 3, 3
2, 2, 2, 4
2, 1, 4, 3
2, 1, 3, 4
1, 4, 4, 1
1, 4, 3, 2
1, 4, 2, 3
1, 4, 1, 4
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 3, 3
1, 3, 2, 4
1, 2, 4, 3
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 1, 4, 4
```

**QUESTION**: Where did my implementation of the restriction on the maximum value of elements go wrong, to cause such increase in the size and complexity of the code?
IOW: Where is the flaw in the algorithm, which causes this code bloat to appear after adding one simple `<= MaxVal` restriction?  Can it be simplified without recursion?

If someone wants to actually compile this, the helper functions are listed below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector> 

void DispVector(const std::vector<unsigned int>& partition)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < partition.size() - 1; i++)       //DISPLAY THE VECTOR HERE ...or do sth else with it.
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << partition[i] << ",";

    std::cout << std::setw(2) << partition[partition.size() - 1] << std::endl;
}

unsigned int MaxPartitionVal(const unsigned int myInt, const unsigned int PartitionLen, unsigned int MinVal, unsigned int MaxVal)
{
    if ((myInt < 2) || (PartitionLen < 2) || (PartitionLen > myInt) || (MaxVal < 1) || (MinVal > MaxVal) || (PartitionLen > myInt) || ((PartitionLen*MaxVal) < myInt ) || ((PartitionLen*MinVal) > myInt))  //Sanity checks
        return 0;

    unsigned int last = PartitionLen - 1;

    if (MaxVal + last*MinVal > myInt)
        MaxVal = myInt - last*MinVal;   //It is not always possible to start with the Maximum Value. Decrease it to sth possible

    return MaxVal;
}

unsigned int MinPartitionVal(const unsigned int myInt, const unsigned int PartitionLen, unsigned int MinVal, unsigned int MaxVal)
{
    if ((MaxVal = MaxPartitionVal(myInt, PartitionLen, MinVal, MaxVal)) == 0)   //Assume that MaxVal has precedence over MinVal
        return (unsigned int)(-1);

    unsigned int last = PartitionLen - 1;

    if (MaxVal + last*MinVal > myInt)
        MinVal = myInt - MaxVal - last*MinVal;  //It is not always possible to start with the Minimum Value. Increase it to sth possible

    return MinVal;
}

//
// Put the definition of GenCompositions() here....
//

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GenCompositions(10, 4, 1, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

*NOTE: the (top-bottom) lexicographic order of the compositions generated by these functions is not optional. ...nor is the skipping of the "do loop" iterations, that do NOT generate valid compositions.*

Comment: Please supply a `main` function.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie:  Done. At the end of the helper functions.

Comment: Why is this being voted up and down without feedback/comments? Why the vote to close it? What's wrong with this question and what can I do to improve it ?

Comment: Close votes come with a reason.

Comment: @LF: The close reason states it is "unclear what the question is", but my Question was clearly marked in bold since the beginning. Now, I have added an "In other Words" (IOW) phrasing to the question.

Comment: "Where did my implementation of the restriction on the maximum value of elements go wrong, to cause such increase in the size and complexity of the code?" is unclear (or too broad) for SO, I guess.  It is more of a design problem.

Comment: In the version with the max value restriction you're calling `MaxPartitionVal` two times, one directly in `GenCompositions` and another in `MinPartitionVal`, you could remove the one from `MinPartitionVal` since it's already called right before.

Comment: @Silvano:  You are correct of course but my concern was mainly with the algorithm design which is inside the "do loop"

Comment: Your functions do not compile. One example: _"error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'"_ on the line `return unsigned int (-1);`. The compile errors are easy to fix, but their existence puts your question in a bad light.

Comment: @JaMiT: Thank you for this observation but I cannot replicate this error while casting `-1` to `unsigned int`.  What compiler and compiler settings give you this error ?  What fix works for this error on your compiler?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson I am using [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) with the gcc compilers (I just rechecked with head, 9.1.0, and 4.4.7). I also tried clang (head and 8.0.0) and while the error message has a different wording (_"expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"_), it still does not like that line. What compiler are *you* using? Fixes include parentheses (`return (unsigned int)(-1);`), dropping an unnecessary keyword (`return unsigned(-1);`), and being less cryptic (`return std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Algorithm**

An iterative algorithm to generate compositions with restricted number of parts and mininum and maximum value is not that complicated. The combination of fixed length and minimum value actually makes things easier; we can keep the minimum value in every part at all times, and just move the "extra" value around to generate the different compositions.

I'll be using this example:

```
n=15, length=4, min=3, max=5
```

We will start by creating a composition with minimum values:

```
3,3,3,3
```

and then we distribute the left-over value, 15 - 12 = 3, over the parts, starting at the first part and moving right each time we reach the maximum value:

```
5,4,3,3
```

This is the first composition. We will then repeatedly transform the composition to get the reverse-lexicographically next one, using these rules:

We start each step by finding the right-most part whose value is greater than the minimum value. *(Actually this can be simplified; see updated code example at the end of this answer.)* If this part is not the last part, we subtract 1 from it, and add 1 to the part to the right of it, e.g.:

```
5,4,3,3
  ^
5,3,4,3
```

and that is the next composition. If the right-most non-minimum part is the last part, things are a little more complicated. We reduce the value of the last part to the minimum, and store the "extra" value in a temporary total, e.g.:

```
3,4,3,5
      ^
3,4,3,3   + 2
```

We then move further left until we find the next part whose value is greater than the minimum value:

```
3,4,3,3   + 2
  ^
```

If the number of parts to the right of this part (2) can hold the temporary total plus 1, we subtract 1 from the current part, and add 1 to the temporary total, and then distribute the temporary total, starting at the part to the right of the current part:

```
3,3,3,3   + 3
    ^
3,3,5,4
```

and that is our next composition. If the parts to the right of the non-minimum part had not been able to hold the temporary total plus 1, we would have again reduced that part to the minimum value and added the "extra" value to the temporary total, and looked further left, e.g. (using a different example with n=17):

```
5,3,4,5
      ^
5,3,4,3   + 2
    ^
5,3,3,3   + 3
^
4,3,3,3   + 4
  ^
4,5,5,3
```

and that is our next composition. If we are moving left to find a non-minimum value, but reach the first part without having found one, we are past the last composition, e.g.:

```
3,3,4,5
      ^
3,3,4,3   + 2
    ^
3,3,3,3   + 3
?
```

That means that `3,3,4,5` was the last composition.

As you see this needs only space for one composition and the temporary total, iterates over each composition once from right to left to find non-minimum parts, and iterates over the composition once from left to right to distribute the temporary total. All the compositions it creates are valid, and in reverse lexicographical order.

---

**Code example**

I first wrote this straightforward translation into C++ of the algorithm explained above. Finding the right-most non-minimum part and distributing values over the composition is done by two helper functions. The code follows the explanation step by step, but that is not the most efficient way to code it. See further below for an improved version.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

void DisplayComposition(const std::vector<unsigned int>& comp)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < comp.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << comp[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Distribute(std::vector<unsigned int>& comp, const unsigned int part, const unsigned int max, unsigned int value) {
    for (unsigned int p = part; value && p < comp.size(); ++p) {
        while (comp[p] < max) {
            ++comp[p];
            if (!--value) break;
        }
    }
}

int FindNonMinPart(const std::vector<unsigned int>& comp, const unsigned int part, const unsigned int min) {
    for (int p = part; p >= 0; --p) {
        if (comp[p] > min) return p;
    }
    return -1;
}

void GenerateCompositions(const unsigned n, const unsigned len, const unsigned min, const unsigned max) {
    if (len < 1 || min > max || n < len * min || n > len * max) return;
    std::vector<unsigned> comp(len, min);
    Distribute(comp, 0, max, n - len * min);
    int part = 0;

    while (part >= 0) {
        DisplayComposition(comp);
        if ((part = FindNonMinPart(comp, len - 1, min)) == len - 1) {
            unsigned int total = comp[part] - min;
            comp[part] = min;
            while (part && (part = FindNonMinPart(comp, part - 1, min)) >= 0) {
                if ((len - 1 - part) * (max - min) > total) {
                    --comp[part];
                    Distribute(comp, part + 1, max, total + 1);
                    total = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    total += comp[part] - min;
                    comp[part] = min;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (part >= 0) {
            --comp[part];
            ++comp[part + 1];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    GenerateCompositions(15, 4, 3, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Improved code example**

Actually, most of the calls to `FindNonMinPart` are unnecessary, because after you've re-distributed values, you know exactly where the right-most non-minimum part is, and there's no need to search for it again. Re-distributing the extra value can also be simplified, with no need for a function call.

Below is a more efficient code version that takes these things into account. It walks left and right through the parts, searching for non-minimum parts, re-distributing extra value and outputting compositions as soon as they are completed. It is noticably faster than the first version (although the calls to `DisplayComposition` obviously take up most of the time).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

void DisplayComposition(const std::vector<unsigned int>& comp)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < comp.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << comp[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void GenerateCompositions(const unsigned n, const unsigned len, const unsigned min, const unsigned max) {

    // check validity of input
    if (len < 1 || min > max || n < len * min || n > len * max) return;

    // initialize composition with minimum value
    std::vector<unsigned> comp(len, min);

    // begin by distributing extra value starting from left-most part
    int part = 0;
    unsigned int carry = n - len * min;

    // if there is no extra value, we are done
    if (carry == 0) {
        DisplayComposition(comp);
        return;
    }

    // move extra value around until no more non-minimum parts on the left
    while (part != -1) {

        // re-distribute the carried value starting at current part and go right
        while (carry) {
            if (comp[part] == max) ++part;
            ++comp[part];
            --carry;
        }

        // the composition is now completed
        DisplayComposition(comp);

        // keep moving the extra value to the right if possible
        // each step creates a new composition
        while (part != len - 1) {
            --comp[part];
            ++comp[++part];
            DisplayComposition(comp);
        }

        // the right-most part is now non-minimim
        // transfer its extra value to the carry value
        carry = comp[part] - min;
        comp[part] = min;

        // go left until we have enough minimum parts to re-distribute the carry value
        while (part--) {

            // when a non-minimum part is encountered
            if (comp[part] > min) {

                // if carry value can be re-distributed, stop going left
                if ((len - 1 - part) * (max - min) > carry) {
                    --comp[part++];
                    ++carry;
                    break;
                }

                // transfer extra value to the carry value
                carry += comp[part] - min;
                comp[part] = min;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    GenerateCompositions(15, 4, 3, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson Hm, just tested a few large cases, and it doesn't seem to be faster than your original code. Maybe this is as good as it gets. What kind of numbers are you running this with anyway?

Comment: Usually, I use CompositionLen around 28 and various MinVal (but always >= 1) and various MaxVal. Rarely, I use huge CompositionLen but only with MaxVal-MinVal<3. I like your analysis of the algorithm even if your implementation is not faster.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson You could try using C-style arrays, limiting the integer sizes to what you actually need, stuff like that. But those are micro-optimizations that probably won't have much impact.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson I can see possibilities with bit patterns, but I think you'd have to write dedicated versions of the code for every value of max-min to be efficient. There are bit hacks to find the right-most non-zero bit in an integer, and you can set all the bits on the right to 0 in one go, so it may be quicker than needing loops to search through the parts.

Answer (score 0):

This Algorithm can be implemented very easily using depth first search and an recursive algorithm. Because you can not use recursion, you can use a stack to simulate the function calls.

Here is one possible solution:

```
void GenCompositions(
    unsigned int value,
    const unsigned int CompositionLen,
    const unsigned int min,
    const unsigned int max
) {
    using composition_t = std::vector<int>;
    using stackframe = std::pair<composition_t::iterator, unsigned int>;

    // Create a vector with size CompositionLen and fill it with the
    // minimum allowed value
    composition_t composition(CompositionLen, min);

    // Because we may have initialised our composition with non-zero values,
    // we need to decrease the remaining value
    value -= min*CompositionLen;

    // Iterator to where we intend to manipulate our composition
    auto pos = composition.begin();

    // We need the callstack to implement the depth first search in an
    // iterative manner without searching through the composition on
    // every backtrace.
    std::vector<stackframe> callstack;

    // We know, that the composition has a maximum length and so does our
    // callstack. By reserving the memory upfront, we never need to
    // reallocate the callstack when pushing new elements.
    callstack.reserve(CompositionLen);

    // Our main loop
    do {

        // We need to generate a valid composition. To do this, we fill the
        // remaining places of the composition with the maximum allowed
        // values, until the remaining value reaches zero
        for(
            ;
            // Check if we hit the end or the total sum equals the value
            pos != composition.end() && value > 0;
            ++pos
        ) {
            // Whenever we edit the composition, we add a frame to our
            // callstack to be able to revert the changes when backtracking
            callstack.emplace_back(pos, value);

            // calculate the maximum allowed increment to add to the current
            // position in our composition
            const auto diff = std::min(value,max-*pos);

            // *pos might have changed in a previous run, therefore we can
            // not use diff as an offset. Instead we have to assign
            // the correct value.
            *pos = min+diff;
            // We changed our composition, so we have to change the
            // remaining value as well
            value -= diff;
        }

        // If the remaining value is zero we got a correct composition and
        // display it to std::out
        if(value == 0) {
            DisplayVector(
                composition,
                std::distance(composition.begin(), pos),
                min
            );
        }

        // This is our backtracking step. To prevent values below the
        // minimum in our composition we backtrack until we get a value that
        // is higher than the minimum. That way we can decrease this value
        // in the last step by one. Because our for loop that generates the
        // valid composition increases pos once more before exit, we have to
        // look at (pos-1).
        while(*(pos-1) <= min) {
            // If our callstack is empty, we can not backtrack further and
            // terminate the algorithm
            if(callstack.empty()) {
                return;
            }
            // If backtracking is possible, we get tha last values from the
            // callstack and reset our state
            pos = callstack.back().first;
            value = callstack.back().second;
            // After this is done, we remove the last frame from the stack
            callstack.pop_back();
        }

        // The last step is to decrease the value in the composition and
        // increase the remaining value to generate the next composition
        --*(pos-1);
        ++value;
    } while(true);
}
```

I also changed the interface of `DisplayVector`, here is a possible implementation:

```
// Because we stop stepping deeper in our DFS tree, if the remaining value
// is zero, the composition may have wrong values behind pos. This is no
// problem for us, because we know these values have to be the minimum
// allowed value.
void DisplayVector(const std::vector<int>& vector, size_t pos, int minval) {

    // I prefere to print opening an closing brackets around sequences
    std::cout << "{ ";
    // The ostream_iterator is a addition, that comes with C++17.
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout, " ");
    // If you can't use C++17, you can use a for loop with an index
    // from 0 to pos to print from the composition
    std::copy_n(vector.begin(), pos, out_it);
    // And a for loop to print vector.size() - pos times the value of minval
    // to fill the rest of your composition
    std::fill_n(out_it, vector.size() - pos, minval);
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

To compile this code you need to set the standard to C++17 and include the following headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
```

The `GenCompositions()` does not use C++17 features, so if you can't use a modern compiler, you can reimplement the print funtion and carry on.

Comment: The whole idea of not using recursion was to save the RAM used for the stack.  I wrote that my microcontroller does not have much RAM. Simulating the stack frames in RAM kind of defeats the purpose.  P.S.  I don't have a problem with the new DisplayVector().

Comment: I dont know what your maxlen is, but for small values very little ram is used. The callstack uses sizeof(stackframe)*maxlen bytes of memory. And the stackframe only holds one pointer and one int.